# I want to print both, keys and values of dictionary which I pass in render to a HTML page in Django

Tags: python, html, django

> This loop format in html is only printing the key but not value,I want to print both key and value in html page.

**views.py**

```
def predict(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         dict = {'Name': John, 'Age': 40}
         return render(request,'standalone.html',{'content':dict})
    else:
         return render(request,'test_homepage.html')
```

**satandalone.html**

```
{% for c in content %}
    {{c}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `.items()` to obtain an iterable of 2-tuples.

```
def predict(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         data = {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 40}
         return render(request,'standalone.html',{'content': data.items()})
    else:
         return render(request,'test_homepage.html')
```

In the template, you can then render this with:

```
{% for k, v in content %}
    {{ k }}: {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `dict`, it overrides the reference to the `dict`
>   class. Use for example `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your template **satandalone.html**:

```
{% for c in content %}
    {{ c.name }}
    {{ c.age }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might help you.

```
{% for key, value in content.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```